# How to survive app from hard reset android phone?

Tags: android, security, rooted-device

i've seen apps like **Cerberus**  which can survive hard reset of phone. I want to add similar functionality in my app that has security features such as anti theft. So my question is: How to create a app that will survive hard reset to preserve some data that might be even used for  further purposes, `How can i prevent my app from hard reset of device?`

I went through the `.zip` file from one of the app which is used to **flash the app to the ROM** but it didn't clear my doubts , can anyone clear the idea about how it can be done

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might consider explaining what you consider a "hard reset" to be, since that term is not used in Android.

Comment: u can even call it factory reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this if you have root permissions by moving the APK to `/system/app`. SuperSu, etc. offer this as an in-app feature. If you really want reliable 'security features' though, the app(s) should be part of the firmware, anything else is snake oil.

Comment: and how can i achieve that

Comment: Either by building your own ROM or by requesting root access on phones that have it and moving the APK.

Comment: yes tht was my question, how can i move my apk to system/data partition, that i want to achieve but i'm confused, can u provide some steps on it

Comment: First, are you sure all devices that this is supposed to run on will have root access?

Comment: can you provide some steps on installin app on system partition

Answer (score 1):

Why not store some data in a file on the SD card? You can simply retrieve this later and phone reset should not affect this. `/sdcard` is not wiped in a factory reset AFAIK.

See:

http://www.androidcentral.com/android-z-f-factory-reset

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33082/does-a-factory-reset-on-a-galaxy-nexus-wipe-the-virtual-sd-card-directory

Comment: i believe there is a way to store some data in system/data folder which wont be wiped on factory reset, i'm looking for such a solution .

Comment: I think the whole point of factory resetting is to clear all data and make the phone like new. Even if there is a loophole that allows this, I recommend against it. You can store your data in a backend server or sdcard or some cloud service (like dropbox to which the user will give you access) etc. This is just my opinion though; You know your requirements better than me.

Comment: as i've mentioned in my question that my app contains a antitheft feature and if we install it normally then it might be lost if someone tries to hard reset the phone, so atleast for such critical features we need to use the "Loophole" in ur language right!!

Comment: okay. I think the cerebrus app uses their own backend server to store user data.

Comment: plus cerberus can also be installed in system/data partition and thats what i'm looking to implement in my application